Virtualbox 7.0.20 NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
I was trying to install the vbox extension pack, but when i try to install it on my Ubuntu 24 machine, it gives this error:
Failed to load the main module ('/usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxPuelMain.so'): VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND - /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxPuelMain.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK9RTCString8endsWithEPKc. 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X80004005)
Component: 
ExtPackManagerWrap
Interface: 
IExtPackManager {70401eef-c8e9-466b-9660-45cb3e9979e4}

Please help!!
